# connecting p-trap to female galvanized tee

Tags: bathroom, drain-waste-vent

This may be a simple problem, but I'm not so knowledgeable about this section of the drainage system specifics.

So, I have a bathroom sink with PVC trap, and I replaced the popup assembly. The pipes were old, so while I had the p-trap off, I decided to replace it. During the process, with not much force, a 1-1/4 galvanized nipple broke at the galvanized female tee flush with the wall. The nipple had a metal compression nut at the end to connect to the p-trap.

So, the inside of the tee had a bit of rust/nipple material inside, and I did a bit of work cleaning the threads with an old screwdriver, a dremel tool with a disk sander, and using a 1-1/2 inch wire disk brush connected to my drill to help clean it out, along with some liquid wrench which may not have done anything. But it's fairly clean, and I think I could screw in pvc mpt adapter. I can screw in a galvanized nipple a few turns, but not enough to be secure, but I'm hoping a pvc adapter will be more forgiving of imperfect threads (?).

I'm hoping I can use a pvc mpt-to-slip adapter, glue in a small section of pipe, buy the compression nut and washer to go over it, and connect it to the standard p-trap arm, etc. Does this sound right?

I keep reading about trap adapters, but I don't see how any I've seen would do anything useful for this setup even if I could find one the right size. Do trap adapters serve any useful purpose for this case?

I have a plumber scheduled for next week, but if I can do it myself, I can save a couple hundred dollars or more.

Comment: You ***need*** to remove the broken part still in the threads. Or hire someone else to remove it for you. You will NOT get a reliable leak-proof seal on tapered pipe threads with an obstruction preventing them from being properly tightened. There are special wrenches for the job that can be purchased, may be available for rental at a local tool rental place, or that come with the professional you hire to deal with it for you.

Comment: I have removed the broken part from the threads, but it's not perfect. I can screw a steel nipple in fairly tight, but I don't know if I trust it. But remember, this is not under pressure, it's a sink drain. But it may not matter, because I discovered that all these pipes have different measurements, so they won't fit together in any way I know about so far. So, probably a plumber will come visit me soon, unless I decide to continue using a bucket - that'll save water, since I can reuse the water for flushing the toilet or irrigation. :-(

Comment: I'd open up the wall and replace the whole unit. Patch up the wall and rest easy.